# Keeping a client-side sync of Sails.js collection, using sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

I very much like Meteor's pub/sub. I wonder if there is a way to get a similar workflow, using [sails.js](/questions/tagged/sails.js) or just a socket library in general.

In particular, what I would like to be able to do is something along the lines of:

```
// Server-side:
App.publish('myCollection', -> collection.find({}))

// Client-side:
let myCollection = App.subscribe('myCollection')
let bob = myCollection.find({name: 'Bob'})
myCollection.insert({name: 'Amelie'}, callback)
```

All interaction with the server should happen in the background.

Comment: Sails.js has [resourceful pubsub](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I very much like Meteor's pub/sub. I wonder if there is a way to get a similar workflow, using sails.js or just a socket library in general

Basically **yes**, at least about realtime sync between backend and frontend. Let's review what meteor's have and answer point by point.

#### Pub/sub

The [Pub / Sub](https://www.meteor.com/try/11) concept, as stated by Sabbir, is also [supported by sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub). Though the basics are slightly different :

- In *meteor*, the client can **subscribes to everything he wants**, and the server control what it receives by **only publishing to who he wants**;
- whereas in *sails.js*, the server both does **subscribe some clients sockets** and **publish to all binded sockets**

Note that, by default:

- *meteor* contains the *autopublish* package that just **notify every client** without any kind of filtering. To acheive some filtering, you have to `meteor remove autopublish` then you can handle what will your client receive by adding a mongo request to it, like explained [here](https://www.meteor.com/try/11).
- *sails* by default, on its automatic "select" blueprints actions, **[auto-subscribes](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/subscribe.html?q=blueprints-and-subscribe()) the calling socket to the events on the objects returned by the "select"**.

As a server-side conclusion:

- Subscribe: just call `find`or `findOne` blueprint default action, through a socket (attaching some `where` filters or not) and your socket will automatically be subscribed to every events concerning returned objects => you don't have to code anything on the server, in most cases, for the `Subscribe` logic.
- Publish: every blueprint default actions (`create`, `update`, `destroy`, `add`, `remove`) auto-publish to subscribed sockets => you don't have to code anything on the server, in most cases, for the `Publish` logic.

(Though, if you find yourself implementing some manual controller actions, sails API helps you [publish](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/publishCreate.html)ing and [subscrib](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/subscribe.html)ing easily)

#### Client handling

Therefore, with both *meteor* and *sails*, clients only receive what they're supposed to receive. Time for front-end now.

Philosophy

- *meteor* in one hand, with it's isomorphic dimension, does provide a front-end connector by nature, exposing it's [data-bound collections](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection).
- *sails* on the other hand, is **front-end agnostic**, and can be attacked by any http REST connector (JS or not), such as [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), or more advanced ones like [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular).
  Though, being aware of the complexity using raw sockets on their API (when it comes to session, CORS, CSRF and stuff), they developped a javascript **socket.io wrapper called [sails.io.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js)** designed to be REST-like-over-socket, and just works like a charm.

Basically, The main difference is that *meteor* is one step higher-level than *sails*, because it provides the logic of **syncing** collections and objects.

> All interaction with the server should happen in the background.

*sails.io.js*, the official front-end component, is just not **that** high-level. When it comes to Angular.js.

Though, you can find some **community connectors** that aim to, kinda, provide the same feature as mongo data-bound collections and objects. There is [sails-resource](https://github.com/Mordred/sails-resource), [spinnaker](https://github.com/xdissent/spinnaker) or [angular resource sails](https://github.com/angular-resource-sails/angular-resource-sails). I tried both of them, and I should say that I was disapointed. The abstraction level is so high that it just becomes annoying, IMHO. For example, with not-very-RESTful-friendly custom actions, like a `login`, it becomes **very hard to adapt it for your needs**.

==> I would advice to use a low-level connector, such as [angularSails](https://github.com/balderdashy/angularSails) or (my prefered) https://github.com/janpantel/angular-sails, or even raw sails.io.js if you're not using Angular.

Edit: just foun a [backbone version](https://github.com/balderdashy/backbone-to-sails), by the sails' creator

It just works great, and believe me, the "*keep my collection in sync with that socket*" code is so ridiculous, that finding a module for this is **just not worth it**.

#### Some code please, stop talking

> In particular, what I would like to be able to do is something along the lines of:

Server

- Meteor

  ```
  # Server-side:
  App.publish('myCollection', -> collection.find({}))
  ```
- Sails

  ```
  //Nothing to do, just sails generate api myCollection
  ```

Client

- Meteor

  ```
  # Client-side:
  myCollection = App.subscribe('myCollection')
  ```
- Sails, with sails.io.js
  (Here using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) for convenience)

  ```
  var myCollection;
  sails.io.get('/myCollection').then(
    function(res) {
      myCollection = res.data;
    },
    function(err) {
      //Handle error
    }
  );

  sails.io.on('myCollection').function(msg) {
    switch(msg.verb) {
      case 'created':
        myCollection.push(msg.data);
        break;
      case 'updated':
        _.extend(_.find(myCollection, 'id', msg.id), msg.data);
        break;
      case 'destroyed':
        _.remove(myCollection, 'id', msg.id);
        break;
    };
  });
  ```

  (I leave the `find` where and `create` to your imagination with [the doc])

> All interaction with the server should happen in the background.

- Well, Sails, only for angular, with sails ressources

I'm not pretty used to that process, so I leave you reading [here](https://github.com/angular-resource-sails/angular-resource-sails#usage) or [here](https://github.com/xdissent/spinnaker#usage), but once again I'd choose manual `.on()`method.

Comment: In addition, notice that *meteor*'s isomorphic collections and objects, beyond wich is called "3 ways data binding", implements the concept of "offline-sync". Keeping data in cache in a local mini-mongo, and syncing (and merging) it *when network is available* with the main mongo. This is called "4 ways data binding", and I just couldn't find any reliable process to automatically do this using sails.js

Comment: Can you answer this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45431466/how-to-get-current-socket-object-or-id-with-in-a-sails-controller

Comment: Nah sorry I left sails.js long ago.. =)

Answer (score 1):

Since I asked this question, I've learned a few things and some new projects have popped up. I decided against `sails.io`, because when developing with `React.js`,  most of the community's weight is behind `webpack`, but `sails.io` uses `gulp`. I realize these can be used together and there is even an npm package for this, but I wasn't too keen on making my stack bigger than it had to be, so I went with a simple `express.js` server that I could tailor to my needs.

In order to sync my data, I'm using `rethinkdb` which allows me to asynchronously watch the database for changes and then publish the changes to the clients through `websockets`.

- I've set up a simple script where I keep an instance of a `baobab` tree on both the client and the server.
- When the tree gets modified on the server, it sends [transaction data](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab#tree-level) to the appropriate clients through the `websocket`
- The client [merges](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab#tree-level) the transaction with the tree.

This method does not make use of `local storage` and keeps the data in memory in the `node.js` process. The data in the `transaction` is also quite redundant.
The **future plan** has always been to set something up using `redis` and `local storage` ...

... until yesterday when I found [`deepstream.io`](https://deepstream.io/)!

This is a tool that does exactly what I want and need! Nothing more, nothing less.

Another project worth mention is [meatier](https://github.com/mattkrick/meatier):  "like meteor, but meatier". It is composed of many other well supported open source projects, so you could even pick and choose.